# How to combine an initial page loop function with a keyup function?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.6.2

When my page loads, I run a loop that finds input fields, calculates their needed size, and resizes them.  Here's the function:

```
// MINIMIZE TEXT FIELDS ON LOAD
$(":text").each(function() {
    var MyString = $(this).val();
    var MyMax = $(this).attr("maxlength");
    var MySize = minimizeText(MyString, MyMax);
    $(this).attr("size", MySize);
});
```

The loop accesses this function:

```
var minimizeText = function minimizeText(MyString, MyMax) {
var MyLength = MyString.length;
var MySize = MyLength + 5;
if (MySize < MyMax && MySize < 50) {
    return MySize;
} else if (MyMax > 50 ) {
    return 50;
} else {
    return MyMax;
}
}
```

If the user changes the text in the input field, the size is recalculated to fit the text in the field.

```
// MINIMIZE TEXT FIELDS ON KEYUP
$(":text").keyup(function() {
    var MyString = $(this).val();
    var MyMax = $(this).attr("maxlength");
    var MySize = minimizeText(MyString, MyMax);
    $(this).attr("size", MySize);
});
```

Both of these work perfectly well.  My goal here is to condense this code and still make it readable.  My question is how can I combine these two so that the text field are checked on load as well as on keyup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your keyup handler is the same as the function that you pass into the initial call to `.each()`. You can define a single function and pass it in as an argument. eg.

```
function resize_handler() { ... }
$(':text').keyup(resize_handler).each(resize_handler);
```